# C# write memorystream to file

Tags: c#, memorystream

I have an easy function, which should receive Stream object and write it to the file "result.txt"
Here is my function:

```
public void WriteToFile(Stream stream)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo("result.txt");
            FileStream fs = f.Create();
            stream.CopyTo(fs);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

But I have an issue with writing to the file. In result - file is empty. But, I receive output in console from this line of code:

```
var text = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

In console I get simple and short json output

```
{"startAt":0,"maxResults":0,"total":472,"issues":[]}
```

This function works fine with other, larger streams, but this 52 Byte stream just does not want to be written to the file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never dispose the `FileStream`, so its internal buffers never get flushed. Use a `using` block to dispose the `FileStream`

Comment: (Also, it's easier to write `FileStream fs = File.Create("result.txt")` rather than going via the `FileInfo`)

Comment: It's also a little suspect to create the `StreamReader` first and then keep manipulating the `stream` object you've given it (in terms of changing its position). Probably fine so long as you don't try and use the reader until the end (as here), but if so why not delay creating the `reader`.

Comment: @canton7
Great answer, mate! For some reason little streams need to be disposed to be written from the buffer to the Disk, but the large ones does not. Why is that so? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: Dear, you should always dispose any type of resource that you use, at the end of your work to prevent garbage collection or memory leak overhead. Disposing mechanism can be done with the explicit Dispose() method or Using block.

Comment: @Radcriminal Larger ones do, too. The `FileStream` contains an internal buffer. When you write to the `FileStream`, it first fills up this buffer, then when the buffer is full it flushes it to disk and then starts filling it again. This is to avoid lots of small writes to disk, which is inefficient. If you don't dispose the `FileStream`, whatever is in its internal buffer is not flushed. If you write a small amount, which fits inside the buffer, nothing will be written unless you flush. If you write a large amount, some will be written but there may still be data left in the buffer which isn't

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need any StreamReader, just do it like this:

```
public void WriteToFile(Stream stream)
{
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       
        using(var fs = new FileStream("/path/to/file", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
             stream.CopyTo(fs);
        }
}

//var memoryStream...
//...

WriteFoFile(memoryStream);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I guess the best answer was given by canton7. You tell me use "using" block to dispose FileStream. For some reason, large streams writes itself from the buffer to the disk, but the little ones need to be disposed before. Why is that so? Where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
public void WriteToFile(Stream stream)
{
    var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("result.txt");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(line);          
    }
 
    var text = reader.ReadToEnd();

    writer.Close();
    reader.Close();

    Console.WriteLine(text);

}
```